# I am trying to make an object resize based on the distance between the cursor and said object. The Y value I get is always naN

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my js code, I always get a naN as a result of my Y variable

```
var elm = document.getElementById("qrcode");
elm.addEventListener("mousemove",getcordd , false)

function getcordd(ev){
  var bdns = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = ev.clientx - bdns.left;
  var y = ev.clienty - bdns.top;
  console.log (`${y}`);
}
```

Comment: MouseEvent.clientx is `undefined` try using uppercase "X" `.clientX`

Comment: Do you know how I would use the answer from a mathematical equation based on this to scale a div?

Comment: you can change the style of your elements in js using the style property [more information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp)
e.g.
`document.getElementById("qrcode").style.width = "300px";` 
would change the the width of your element to 300px

Comment: Are you wanting the amount of change to depend on distance from the center of the object or from thr nearest edge? And do you want the object to scale or to actually change its dimensions (and hence its midpoint position)?

Answer (score 0):

I got carried away here, but reading that you wanted to know about changing an element's size based on mouse movements, I threw this thing together. Take a look and if you have any questions about it, let me know in a comment. Cheers

```js
var elm = document.getElementById("qrcode");
document.getElementById("mousecapture").addEventListener("mousemove", getcordd, false)

function getcordd(ev) {
  var bdns = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  // console.log(bdns)
  var x = ev.clientX - bdns.left;
  var y = ev.clientY - bdns.top;
  // console.log(`${y}`, `${x}`, bdns.left, bdns.top);

  // resize the div
  //console.log(ev.clientX, ev.clientX/bdns.width,ev.clientY, ev.clientY/bdns.height)
  let min = 10,
    max = 200; // min width/height;
  elm.style.width = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, Math.round(max * Math.abs(x / bdns.width)))) + "px";

  elm.style.height = Math.max(min, Math.min(max, Math.round(max * Math.abs(y / bdns.height)))) + "px";

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

#qrcode {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mousecapture {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  Move the mouse in the white box
  <hr>
  <div id='mousecapture'></div>
  <div id='qrcode'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really close to what I want to do thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas - if it answered your question or helped solve, feel free to mark it as the answer. Cheers